# how can i remove "Bluetooth " from the list of wireless & networks (Android Gingerbread)

Tags: java, android, kernel

In my work  I need to remove `"bluetooth`" from settings `"Wireless & networks"` . So I don't know what's the first step. I think that it is to edit  `Kernel`  or UI  of Android.

Please  can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove any part of system unless you are building your own ROM.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the Bluetooth option from settings.apk, all you have to do is delete the bluetooth line from settings.xml(after decompiling settings).

Also, if you want to totally disable bluetooth, you should remove all apks pertaining to bluetooth from system/app. Be careful for fcs though.

Comment: How did you do that ? Can you please explain me how you removed the bluetooth from the settings.apk. and from where have you got the settings.apk ?